# android lint exclude test directories ignore in config not working

Tags: android, lint

I want to configure android lint to ignore test paths and projects using `lint.xml`

sample`lint.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
   ...
  <issue  id="all" severity="ignore" >
    <ignore path="tests/projecttests/res/layout/button.xml" />
    <ignore path="tests/projecttest2s/res/layout/button.xml" />
    <ignore path="tests/projecttests2/res/layout/button.xml" />
    ...
  </issue>
</lint>
```

used sample cmd from offical lint page:

```
lint --check Accessibility --html /var/www/asc/accessibility_report.html --config lint.xml
```

But files in `lint.xml` are not ignored as expected.

I also tried:

```
<ignore path="**/tests/projecttests2/res/layout/button.xml" />
```

but still have same issue.

If I put in `tools:ignore="all"` in specify xml files lint does ignore this file.

Comment: same for me unfortunately, seems to be really buggy there :(